# Delete Internet Connection history from a PC

Tags: internet, connection, history

I need to delete internet connection history from a PC, like it was never ever connected to any form of internet, be it wireless or wired and that none of its apps ever connected to and downloaded anything from the internet; making it just like brand new. NOT TALKING ABOUT BROWSING HISTORY.

Comment: You need a net connection to even authorise the OS these days. This sounds very much like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) so rather than tell us what you think might be the answer to your issue, why don't you tell us what your issue actually is?

Comment: Reinstall the OS from scratch and don't download any updates. Without knowing your operating system no further advice can be given.

Answer (score 2):

this is not possible to 100% in WindowsXP-10 because as soon as you are connected to Internet it starts creating different Update and Connection details to dozens and hundreds of places also a lot of apps cache recent connections. so instead of doing that you would be better of reinstalling windows with a fresh win10 USB-Stick (most recent version) and just NOT Connect any internet at all.......
i can´t think of another way. if your talking about windows....

Comment: Though this is factually correct, I don't think it's what the OP is actually looking for. I'd wait for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

In Control panel open network and sharing center, then click on the Icon next to network, when it opens click merge or delete network connections.

Comment: That will remove the connection but doesn't answer the OPs question of making it so there is zero evidence of ever being connected to the internet. There have likely been updates that have occurred over time.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are worried about WiFi passwords that you have stored on your computer
and would like to remove them all.

You can do that by starting an elevated Command Prompt (cmd) and entering
the following command:

```
netsh wlan delete profile name=* i=*
```

You can also use the graphical utility
[WirelessKeyView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wireless_key.html)
to visually show, save and also selectively delete profiles.